# user agent stylesheet override my own styles

Tags: html, css, rendering, user-agent

EDIT*** In what instances can user agent styles override custom CSS?

---

I have a few styles set on an element on a page of mine, it seems that the user agent stylesheet override my definitions.

It is happening in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m, Firefox 34.0.5, but not in IE 11.

I know I don't have any direct styles on that element, but it is my understanding that the user agent stylesheet ONLY takes over if there are absolutely no styles for a particular element.  Do inherited styles not count towards that?

[image]

Comment: You should include sufficient HTML and CSS, as text, for reproducing the issue.

Comment: I would have to post pages of CSS and HTML.  I figured by simply posting the calculated styles as per Chrome developer tools you would be able to see that there are styles applied to the element, but they are getting overridden with user agent styles.  I guess I should post in my question "In what instances can user agent styles override custom CSS?" - I will do that now.

Comment: No, you should have posted a *minimal* document that actually demonstrates the problem. But in my answer below I think I have reconstructed a simple case. And you should not change a question to a substantially different question, or to ask a general question when you have a specific problem. General questions are often closed as too broad (and even if not, answers to them might not solve your real problem).

Comment: Great answer below. Seems to answer the original question - "Do inherited styles not count towards that?" which is very close to the revised question - " In what instances can user agent styles override custom CSS?".  Thank you for explaining this to me.  I understood more specific CSS rules have priority but I suppose I misunderstood certain resources when looking up the subject of user agent stylesheets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer to the general question is that only property settings set on an element itself are taken into account when deciding which style setting “wins”. For example, if we have just one style sheet that sets `font-size: 18px` on the `body` element and another style sheet that set `font-size: 9px` on all `p` elements, then the font size of `p` elements is 9px, no matter what the origins of the style sheets are, e.g. whether the latter is just a browser default style sheet. Inheritance plays no role here. This is all described in section [Assigning property values, Cascading, and Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) of the CSS 2.1 spec.

Inheritance is considered only after the above “fight” has been resolved. Only then are inheritable properties inherited by elements that have them not set *at all*.

The specific question does not provide specific code, but it can be inferred that you have something like this:

```
 <style>
   body { font-size: 12px; }
 </style>
 <table>
   <tr><td>foo
 </table>
 bar
```

Normally this causes both “foo” and “bar” to appear in 12px size. The table cell inherits the size from the table row, which inherits it from the `tbody` element, which inherits it from the table, which inherits it from the `body`.

However, in your case, this chain is broken. The reason is that the browser style sheet has

```
 table { font-size: medium }
```

which in practice tends to mean 16px. Now the `table` element has the property set, so the cell inherits that value.

Browsers do not normally have such a rule in their style sheets. However, in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), most browsers apply the rule. This means that font size is not inherited from `body` into tables. This reflects bugs (or oddities) in very old versions of IE and lets legacy page be rendered as they used to be.

If you have unintentionally caused Quirks Mode and do not need it for other purposes, just slap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the very start of your document. But beware that old pages may get messed up in different ways, if they have been designed in testing conditions that correspond to Quirks Mode.

Alternatively, add the following rule into your style sheet:

```
table { font-size: 100% }
```

This means that a table gets the font size of its parent. (Like in inheritance, but safer.)

Answer (score 0):

use a normalize.css to avoid this issue, if not set none style to an element, he inherit the user agent style.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this.  But I have styles applied to the element already.  My question is why is it overriding the styles which are applied to the element.